# How to plot candlestick hourly with bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have try to plot the candlestick chart.
[image: figure 1]

From above figure you will see that the x-axis is sequences of data,
I just want to replace it by use date from df['date']

I try to use df['date'] instead df['seq'] but it doesn't work because time format.

How should i solve it?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
import datetime
import random
import numpy

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import *
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import gridplot, show

lenght = 20
df = pandas.DataFrame()
date = []
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(10,15):
        date.append(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, i, j, 0))

df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df['open'] = [random.randint(40,50) for p in range(lenght)]
df['high'] = [random.randint(40,50) for p in range(lenght)]
df['low'] = [random.randint(40,50) for p in range(lenght)]
df['close'] = [random.randint(40,50) for p in range(lenght)]
df['rsi'] = [random.randint(0,100) for p in range(lenght)]

seqs=numpy.arange(df.shape[0])
df["seq"]=pandas.Series(seqs)
df['mid']=df.apply(lambda x:(x['open']+x['close'])/2,axis=1)
df['height']=df.apply(lambda x:abs(x['close']-x['open'] if x['close']!=x['open'] else 0.001),axis=1)

df["seq"] = df['date']
inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w=0.3

#use ColumnDataSource to pass in data for tooltips
sourceInc=ColumnDataSource(ColumnDataSource.from_df(df.loc[inc]))
sourceDec=ColumnDataSource(ColumnDataSource.from_df(df.loc[dec]))

#the values for the tooltip come from ColumnDataSource
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("date", "@date"),
        ("close", "@close"),
    ]
)

TOOLS = [CrosshairTool(), hover, BoxZoomTool(), WheelZoomTool()]

ohlc = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=500, tools=TOOLS, x_axis_type='datetime')
ohlc.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
ohlc.segment(df.seq[inc], df.high[inc], df.seq[inc], df.low[inc], color="red")
ohlc.segment(df.seq[dec], df.high[dec], df.seq[dec], df.low[dec], color="green")
ohlc.rect(x='date', y='mid', width=w, height='height', fill_color="red", line_color="red", source=sourceInc)
ohlc.rect(x='date', y='mid', width=w, height='height', fill_color="green", line_color="green", source=sourceDec)
ohlc.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 3.14/4

rsi = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=100, y_range=(0,100))
rsi.xaxis.visible = False
rsi.multi_line(xs=[df.seq]*3, ys=[df.rsi, [30]*df.shape[0], [70]*df.shape[0]], line_color=['brown','grey','grey'], line_width=1)

chart = gridplot([[ohlc, None],[rsi, None]],toolbar_location='left')
print(df.date)
show(chart)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace the `w=0.3` constant to `w = 0.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000  # half hour in ms`.
`w` means `candlestick_width`